# Slow network in Docker container after OpenShift install

Tags: networking, docker, openshift, bandwidth

After installing CentOS 7 VM in Google Cloud (n1-standard-2) with CentOS' own Docker packages (docker-1.10.3-44) the network performance is as expected.
Downloading a 100MB file from within a Docker container with wget takes 18 secs.

However if the same node is part of an OpenShift Origin (1.1) installation (with default network settings wherever applicable), the network performance from Docker containers decreases drastically after running the OpenShift Origin Ansible scripts, the download of the 100MB file from above now takes over an hour! This affects both master and node members of the OpenShift cluster.

This only affects bandwidth from the container, the network performance from the CentOS host is unaffected. Also it only affects throughput. Ping times from the container are also unaffected.

I've reproduced this behaviour several times. I have however only been able to set up OpenShift clusters on Google Cloud yet (tried an AWS installation, but that failed for unrelated reasons).

I'm brand new to OpenShift, have spent a fair amount looking for online help for this issue but without luck so far.

UPDATE:

A tcpdump of the beginning of an HTTP connection taken on the container's interface (eth0) yields the following:

```
17:03:19.088683 IP 10.168.245.2.35050 > 54.76.101.68.80: Flags [S],
seq 1295390892, win 27400, options [mss 1370,sackOK, TS val 23947380
ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0

17:03:19.106395 IP 54.76.101.68.80 > 10.168.245.2.35050: Flags [S.],
seq 403807014, ack 1295390893, win 26847, options [mss 1460,sackOK,
TS val 192703377 ecr 23947380,nop,wscale 7], length 0

17:03:19.106436 IP 10.168.245.2.35050 > 54.76.101.68.80: Flags [.],
ack 1, win 215, options [nop,nop,TS val 23947398 ecr 192703377],
length 0

17:03:19.106615 IP 10.168.245.2.35050 > 54.76.101.68.80: Flags [P.],
seq 1:147, ack 1, win 215, options [nop,nop,TS val 23947398
ecr 192703377], length 146: HTTP: GET /20 HTTP/1.1

17:03:19.122771 IP 54.76.101.68.80 > 10.168.245.2.35050: Flags [.],
ack 147, win 219, options [nop,nop,TS val 192703381 ecr 23947398],
length 0
(*)
17:03:19.152665 IP 54.76.101.68.80 > 10.168.245.2.35050: Flags [.],
seq 13581:14939, ack 147, win 219, options [nop,nop,TS val 192703389
ecr 23947398], length 1358: HTTP

17:03:19.152691 IP 10.168.245.2.35050 > 54.76.101.68.80: Flags [.],
ack 1, win 236, options [nop,nop,TS val 23947444
ecr 192703381,nop,nop,sack 1 {13581:14939}], length 0

17:03:19.384706 IP 54.76.101.68.80 > 10.168.245.2.35050: Flags [.],
seq 1:1359, ack 147, win 219, options [nop,nop,TS val 192703447
ecr 23947444], length 1358: HTTP: HTTP/1.1 200 OK

17:03:19.384738 IP 10.168.245.2.35050 > 54.76.101.68.80: Flags [.],
ack 1359, win 257, options [nop,nop,TS val 23947676
ecr 192703447,nop,nop,sack 1 {13581:14939}], length 0

17:03:19.616700 IP 54.76.101.68.80 > 10.168.245.2.35050: Flags [.],
seq 1359:2717, ack 147, win 219, options [nop,nop,TS val 192703505
ecr 23947676], length 1358: HTTP

17:03:19.616735 IP 10.168.245.2.35050 > 54.76.101.68.80: Flags [.],
ack 2717, win 278, options [nop,nop,TS val 23947908
ecr 192703505,nop,nop,sack 1 {13581:14939}], length 0

17:03:19.633035 IP 54.76.101.68.80 > 10.168.245.2.35050: Flags [P.],
seq 14939:16297, ack 147, win 219, options [nop,nop,TS val 192703509
ecr 23947908], length 1358: HTTP

17:03:19.633066 IP 10.168.245.2.35050 > 54.76.101.68.80: Flags [.],
ack 2717, win 299, options [nop,nop,TS val 23947925
ecr 192703505,nop,nop,sack 1 {13581:16297}], length 0

17:03:19.633036 IP 54.76.101.68.80 > 10.168.245.2.35050: Flags [.],
seq 16297:17655, ack 147, win 219, options [nop,nop,TS val 192703509
ecr 23947908], length 1358: HTTP

17:03:19.633073 IP 10.168.245.2.35050 > 54.76.101.68.80: Flags [.],
ack 2717, win 321, options [nop,nop,TS val 23947925
ecr 192703505,nop,nop,sack 1 {13581:17655}], length 0

[...]
```

If I take the same tcpdump on the CentOS VM's network interface (eth0) I get this:

```
17:03:19.088888 IP 10.168.16.27.35050 > 54.76.101.68.http: Flags [S],
seq 1295390892, win 27400, options [mss 1370,sackOK,TS val 23947380
ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0

17:03:19.106356 IP 54.76.101.68.http > 10.168.16.27.35050: Flags [S.],
seq 403807014, ack 1295390893, win 26847, options [mss 1460,sackOK,
TS val 192703377 ecr 23947380,nop,wscale 7], length 0

17:03:19.106448 IP 10.168.16.27.35050 > 54.76.101.68.http: Flags [.],
ack 1, win 215, options [nop,nop,TS val 23947398 ecr 192703377],
length 0

17:03:19.106665 IP 10.168.16.27.35050 > 54.76.101.68.http: Flags [P.],
seq 1:147, ack 1, win 215, options [nop,nop,TS val 23947398
ecr 192703377], length 146

17:03:19.122733 IP 54.76.101.68.http > 10.168.16.27.35050: Flags [.],
ack 147, win 219, options [nop,nop,TS val 192703381 ecr 23947398],
length 0
(*)
17:03:19.123098 IP 54.76.101.68.http > 10.168.16.27.35050: Flags [.],
seq 1:5433, ack 147, win 219, options [nop,nop,TS val 192703381
ecr 23947398], length 5432

17:03:19.123173 IP 54.76.101.68.http > 10.168.16.27.35050: Flags [.],
seq 5433:10865, ack 147, win 219, options [nop,nop,TS val 192703381
ecr 23947398], length 5432

17:03:19.123250 IP 54.76.101.68.http > 10.168.16.27.35050: Flags [.],
seq 10865:13581, ack 147, win 219, options [nop,nop,TS val 192703381
ecr 23947398], length 2716

17:03:19.152621 IP 54.76.101.68.http > 10.168.16.27.35050: Flags [.],
seq 13581:14939, ack 147, win 219, options [nop,nop,TS val 192703389
ecr 23947398], length 1358

17:03:19.152702 IP 10.168.16.27.35050 > 54.76.101.68.http: Flags [.],
ack 1, win 236, options [nop,nop,TS val 23947444
ecr 192703381,nop,nop,sack 1 {13581:14939}], length 0

17:03:19.169088 IP 54.76.101.68.http > 10.168.16.27.35050: Flags [.],
seq 1:2717, ack 147, win 219, options [nop,nop,TS val 192703393
ecr 23947444], length 2716

17:03:19.384652 IP 54.76.101.68.http > 10.168.16.27.35050: Flags [.],
seq 1:1359, ack 147, win 219, options [nop,nop,TS val 192703447
ecr 23947444], length 1358

17:03:19.384749 IP 10.168.16.27.35050 > 54.76.101.68.http: Flags [.],
ack 1359, win 257, options [nop,nop,TS val 23947676
ecr 192703447,nop,nop,sack 1 {13581:14939}], length 0

17:03:19.401047 IP 54.76.101.68.http > 10.168.16.27.35050: Flags [.],
seq 1359:4075, ack 147, win 219, options [nop,nop,TS val 192703451
ecr 23947676], length 2716

17:03:19.616644 IP 54.76.101.68.http > 10.168.16.27.35050: Flags [.],
seq 1359:2717, ack 147, win 219, options [nop,nop,TS val 192703505
ecr 23947676], length 1358

17:03:19.616746 IP 10.168.16.27.35050 > 54.76.101.68.http: Flags [.],
ack 2717, win 278, options [nop,nop,TS val 23947908
ecr 192703505,nop,nop,sack 1 {13581:14939}], length 0

17:03:19.632969 IP 54.76.101.68.http > 10.168.16.27.35050: Flags [P.],
seq 14939:16297, ack 147, win 219, options [nop,nop,TS val 192703509
ecr 23947908], length 1358

17:03:19.633023 IP 54.76.101.68.http > 10.168.16.27.35050: Flags [.],
seq 16297:17655, ack 147, win 219, options [nop,nop,TS val 192703509
ecr 23947908], length 1358

17:03:19.633083 IP 10.168.16.27.35050 > 54.76.101.68.http: Flags [.],
ack 2717, win 299, options [nop,nop,TS val 23947925
ecr 192703505,nop,nop,sack 1 {13581:16297}], length 0

17:03:19.633096 IP 10.168.16.27.35050 > 54.76.101.68.http: Flags [.],
ack 2717, win 321, options [nop,nop,TS val 23947925
ecr 192703505,nop,nop,sack 1 {13581:17655}], length 0

17:03:19.649470 IP 54.76.101.68.http > 10.168.16.27.35050: Flags [.],
seq 2717:5433, ack 147, win 219, options [nop,nop,TS val 192703513
ecr 23947925], length 2716

[...]
```

It looks to me as though the first 5 packages perfectly match each other. However the first three packages after (*) on the host tcpdump ('seq 1:5433', 'seq 5433:10865' and 'seq 10865:13581') don't appear in the container tcpdump. The next one ('seq 13581:14939') appears in both again.

UPDATE2:

I also see repeated ICMP packets coming from the host's eth0 to the source IP during slow HTTP transfers:

```
09:57:52.353514 IP 10.168.16.27 > 54.76.101.68: ICMP 10.168.16.27
unreachable - need to frag (mtu 1360), length 556
```

The ICMP packets seem to reach their destination, a web server at AWS in this case. A dump on that server shows:

```
11:32:04.818451 IP 146.148.30.13 > 172.31.1.77: ICMP 146.148.30.13
unreachable - need to frag (mtu 1360), length 556
```

So this does indeed smell of an MTU problem as Clayton suggested below. For clarification I'm seeing the delays from all sources that I have tried, not just from this particular web server.

Andre

Comment: This sounds similar to an MTU mismatch issue, although there are a number of factors in network setup that could have similar outcomes.  Can you check https://docs.openshift.com/enterprise/3.1/admin_guide/sdn_troubleshooting.html#debugging-local-networking (the section on MTU)?

Comment: Hi Clayton, MTU on the host's eth0 is 1460, on the container's eth0 it was 1410. This seems to be consistent with requirements. I've decreased the container MTU further to 1360, but the slowdown remains.
I am however seeing some MTU related ICMP packages as detailed in the update above.

Comment: As of this morning (2016-07-11) this issue has been resolved on all our OpenShift hosts without any further action from our side. So I presume this was a problem with Google Cloud.